# App crashes on iOS when trying to upload image to firebase storage using react native

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

to pick the image i used
`import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';`

image pick process

```
        const permission = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if (permission.granted === false) {
            Alert.alert('You did not accept access to internal storage');
        } else {
            console.log(permission);
            const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
                mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
                allowsEditing: true,
                aspect: [4, 3],
                quality: 1,
            });
            console.log(result);
                if (!result.cancelled) {
                    const imageToUploadUri = result.uri;
                    setImage(imageToUploadUri);
                    Alert.alert('picture loaded now upload it to the storage');
                } else {
                    Alert.alert('You did not chose any image');
                }
        }
    };
```

and the image is set successfully but when i am try to upload this image to firebase storage the app crash only on ios.

the firebase imports i used:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { getDownloadURL, getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from 'firebase/storage';
```

```
// image upload function
export const uploadImage  = async (url: string, clubName: string) => {  
    const storage = getStorage();
    const reffernce = ref(storage, `home_image/${clubName}_main.png`);

    const image = await fetch(url);
    const bytes = await image.blob();

    await uploadBytes(reffernce, bytes);
}
```

Comment: If the app crashes there should be an error message and a stack trace. Please find both and add them to your question.

Answer (score 0):

the error is on

```
const storage = getStorage()
```

getStorage wants an app param to get that app storage.

You should write something like that:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage"

const config = { apiKey: <api_key>, ... }
const app = initializeApp(config)
const storage = getStorage(app)
```

It's recommended to write this in a configuration file (ex: firebaseConfig.js) and then import the storage variable everytime you need